# which zip archive format (.rar or .zip) works with static resources without any issues?

Tags: static-resources

I have created a .rar using winrar that contains images and upload as a static resource, but when i tried to access the images they are not displaying on my vf pages. I looked in "View Page Source" rendered HTML and clicked the rendered resource link and it displays in a blank page with black background with the following error,

> The image
>   "view-source:c.na15.visual.force.com/resource/1400088230000/UtilityImages/…;
>   cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

After that, i created a zip file using winzip and do the same procedure as above and got it worked. Now my questions are,

1. Is static resources recognize the files with only .zip?
2. What are the other zip formats it will accept? (.rar, .jar, .ear, .tar, etc)

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only accepted formats are **`.jar`** and **`.zip`**

> You can package a collection of related files into a directory hierarchy and upload that hierarchy as a .zip or .jar archive.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm

Comment: Note that a JAR is actually a ZIP with a renamed extension. It's use is for Java, of course, but in all other aspects, it is formatted as a normal ZIP file.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I used .zip and without any issue. In [salesforce documentations](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm) also they have mentioned that **`.zip`** and **`.jar`** will work but nothing mentioned about **`.rar`**

If you are using **WinZip** make sure you are using the latest version since [salesforce has announced](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_create.htm) it may loss your data with older versions.

> If you are using WinZip be sure to install the most recent version. Older versions of WinZip may cause a loss of data.

Comment: i have given upvote for your answer @highfive